# CSS max-height not working,but height for same div is working

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my external css file,

```
#slider {
    width:1200px;
    height:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

works, but

```
#slider {
    max-width:1200px;
    max-height:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

does not.
It gives 0 height.
I am on latest chrome browser.
What am I doing wrong?
Also `-webkit-calc(100% - 100px)` or `calc(100% - 100px)` doesnt work.
I am guessing none of css2/css3 properties are working.
This html file I am using is a part of a complex html with many css and javascript includes. Is css2 being blocked or something in some other file?

**UPDATE:**
Specifying min-height works, and sets the height of the div to its value.

Comment: Does your slider look smaller than 1200px when you specify max-width ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `max-width` doesn't set the width, it just says that's how wide the element _can_ be.

Comment: 9 seconds too late!

Comment: I am trying to set the width/height of the slider div.do we need to have both width and max-width property for an element.

Comment: add a `min-height` as well or `height: auto;`

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply `height: 100%;` in addition to the `max-height` which will make the `height` 100% of its parent up to its own `max-height`. Additionally, it can only take up the space of its parent. So, if its a first child to the `body` tag, you would do something like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e48bzv1w/4/) (With smaller width/height for example)

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  max-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And to use `calc()`, it works the same way. It is in relation to its parents height/width. So you could do something like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e48bzv1w/6/)

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do. But I suppose at the moment you have *no* content in that element – if no `height`is defined, the height will depend on the contents. Try to put more and more content/text/images into it – it will grow up to the max-height value, after which a scrollbar will appear.